# PHP - Cant add image name to Database Table

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic, database-connection

**Please Explain this**

The problem i am facing is unable to add the image name to the database table...
It adds the random number but not the image name

**Database Connectivity and inserting data code**

```
        $inst="insert into addgall set 
                id='".$_POST['id']."',
                title='".$_POST['title']."',
                tag1='".$_POST['tag1']."',
                image='".$name."'
                ";

mysql_query($inst);     
}
}
else
{
$sel="select * from addgall where id='".$_GET['upid']."' ";
$exe=mysql_query($sel);
$fetch=mysql_fetch_array($exe);
if($_POST['login']=='Add')
{
$rand=rand(10,99999999);
$name=$rand.$_FILES['image']['name'];
$tmppath=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$path="images/portfolio/".$name;
move_uploaded_file($tmppath,$path);
unlink("images/portfolio/".$fetch['image']);

echo $inst="update addgall set
       title='".$_POST['title']."',
       image='".$name."'
       where id='".$_GET['upid']."'" ;

         mysql_query($inst);

    echo '<script>window.location="Viewgallery.php"</script>';
}
}
?>
```

.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
**This is the form code**

```
<form name="contactForm" id='contact_form' method="post" action=''>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div id='name_error' class='error'>Unique ID of Product</div>
                                    <div>
                                        <input type='text' name='id' id='name' class="form-control" placeholder="Unique ID of Product">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div id='name_error' class='error'>Title of the Product</div>
                                    <div>
                                        <input type='text' name='title' class="form-control" placeholder="Title of the Product">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div id='name_error' class='error'>Tag</div>
                                    <div>
                                        <input type='text' name='tag1' class="form-control" placeholder="Tags seperated by 1 space">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div id='name_error' class='error'>Tag</div>
                                    <div>
                                        <input type='file' name='image' class="form-control" placeholder="Tags seperated by 1 space">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div id='mail_success' class='success'>Your message has been sent successfully.</div>
                                <div id='mail_fail' class='error'>Sorry, error occured this time sending your message.</div>
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                <br>
                                    <p id='submit'>
                                        <input type='submit' value='Add' name='login' class="btn btn-border">
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

you have ignored **enctype=multipart/form-date** in the **form** tag so add the enctype attribute in your form tag it will resolves your problem

```
<form name="contactForm" id='contact_form' method="post" action='' enctype= 'multipart/form-data'>
```

Answer (score 0):

add `enctype= multipart/form-data` in `form` tag.

```
<form name="contactForm" id='contact_form' method="post" action='' enctype= 'multipart/form-data'>
```

Answer (score 0):

add enctype="multipart/form-data" to your form element